# Поле в подзапрос считается как переменная

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Oracle, Toad, PLSQL
Есть база основная с полем VAL, и дополнительная используется как словарь
нужно сделать перевод из O.VAL в U.UKOD

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT U.UNEWKOD
    FROM USLV U
    WHERE O.VAL = U.UKOD) VAL,
    O.VAL
FROM OG O
```

Проблема в том что U.UNEWKOD при запуске оно понимает как переменную и просит ввести ей значение,
хотя если сделать этот подзапрос отдельно то все работает как надо

Comment: Вот если, как ты просишь, `WHERE O.VAL = U.UKOD`, то `SELECT U.UKOD` всё равно что `SELECT O.VAL`. И у тебя получается запрос `SELECT O.VAL VAL, O.VAL FROM OG O`... что явный бред.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не правильно написал поле, исправил, проблема таже

Comment: `SELECT U.UNEWKOD VAL, O.VAL FROM OG O JOIN USLV U ON O.VAL = U.UKOD`

Comment: Привелико благодарю)